# Nesting a Case statement within an IF statement

Tags: sql, db2, case

I'm getting a compiler error on the last CASE statement located in where clause. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong...any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
P1: BEGIN
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT MPWBIPS.MIP_NO,                                  
        MPWBIPS.ITEM_NO,                                 
        MPWBIPS.MATL_PLNR_ID,                            
        MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS,                       
        MPWBMIT.EXCS_ITEM_COST_TOT,
        MPWBMIP.TRGT_CHGOVR_DATE,
        SLOTLOC.LOT_FROM_EFF_DATE,              
    FROM MPWBIPS MPWBIPS                                          
    INNER JOIN MPWBMIT MPWBMIT 
        ON MPWBMIT.MIP_NO = MPWBIPS.MIP_NO             
        AND MPWBMIT.ITEM_NO = MPWBIPS.ITEM_NO 
    INNER JOIN MPPLNR MPPLNR
        ON MPWBIPS.MATL_PLNR_ID = MPPLNR.MATL_PLNR_ID
    INNER JOIN MPWBMIP MPWBMIP
        ON MPWBIPS.MIP_NO = MPWBMIP.MIP_NO
    INNER JOIN SMPROJ_DPIMS SMPROJ
        ON MPWBIPS.MIP_NO = SMPROJ.MIP_NO
    INNER JOIN SLOTLOC_DPIMS SLOTLOC
        ON SMPROJ.MFG_CHGOVR_PER = SLOTLOC.LOT

    WHERE plannerID =
        CASE WHEN mgrIndc = 'Y' THEN
            MPPLNR.MGR_LID
        WHEN suprvIndc = 'Y' THEN
            MPPLNR.SPRVSR_LID
        WHEN plannerID = '' THEN
            ''
        ELSE
            MPPLNR.MATL_PLNR_ID
        END

        AND CASE WHEN obsStatus = 'ACTION' THEN
                    MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS <> 'RESOLVED 99'
                    AND MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS <> 'EXCESS 90'
                WHEN obsStatus = 'ALL' OR obsStatus = '' THEN
                    obsStatus = ''
                ELSE
                    MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS = obsStatus
                END
        AND (COALESCE(mipNo, '') = '' OR MPWBIPS.MIP_NO = mipNo);
OPEN cursor1;
```

END P1

Comment: Expressions do not stand on their own, they need to be assigned to something, a variable or a column. What do you want to do?

Comment: I've removed the if, and the case statement above will still not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest `case` statement within `if` statement. Consider, rewriting your query.

You are missing `case` at end. You case statement should be

```
CASE WHEN obsStatus = 'ACTION' THEN 
MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS <> 'RESOLVED 99'
AND MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS <> 'EXCESS 90'
WHEN obsStatus = 'ALL' OR obsStatus = '' THEN                     
obsStatus = ''                 
ELSE                     
MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS = obsStatus
END CASE
```

EDIT:

`<>` (not equal) operator is creating problem; you can't use them there. Not sure whya you are using Not equal in case condition. below two line

```
MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS <> 'RESOLVED 99'
AND MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS <> 'EXCESS 90'
```

probably make your Where condition something like this:

```
WHERE plannerID = 
(CASE WHEN mgrIndc = 'Y' THEN             
MPPLNR.MGR_LID         
WHEN suprvIndc = 'Y' THEN             
MPPLNR.SPRVSR_LID         
WHEN plannerID = '' THEN  ''         
ELSE MPPLNR.MATL_PLNR_ID         
END)          

AND 

((obsStatus = 'ACTION') and (MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS <> 'RESOLVED 99'
 AND MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS <> 'EXCESS 90'))

or

((obsStatus = 'ALL' OR obsStatus = '') and (obsStatus = ''))

or

MPWBIPS.ITEM_OBS_STATUS = obsStatus

AND 

(COALESCE(mipNo, '') = '' OR MPWBIPS.MIP_NO = mipNo);
```

Comment: I've removed the if statement as shown above. The case statement on it's own is still not compiling.

Comment: Does not make a difference. END and END CASE are evaluated the same.

Comment: Then, your case statement looks fine. Problem is somewhere else in the query. Post the query in question.

Comment: It is the case statement. When removed, the proc can be saved and deployed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you can use an if in this method.  you could nest cases however.

```
case when parm1 <> '' THEN
            CASE parm1 
                WHEN '1' THEN
                    --do something
                WHEN '2' THEN
                    --do something
                ELSE
                    --do something
            END
end
```

But why?  instead just add to your case

```
            CASE parm1

                WHEN '1' THEN
                    --do something
                WHEN '2' THEN
                    --do something
                WHEN <> ''
                    --do something
            END
```